# Pinvoke ONLY code for getting proccess via its name

Tags: c#, .net, performance, process, pinvoke

as i was trying to have a test and learn about native p/invoke functions i was trying to use only pinvoke and then compare the time it takes to get process info with .net simple

```
Process myProc = Process.GetProcessByName("WinRAR");
```

though i feel that i need to realy measure that almost 2 pages in length code, using P/invoke just so i could get same results, but this time ONLY with native code, i guess that it should be faster and i want to  atleast get to benchmark both ,so please help here .

so it seems that my code is 1) ... ok i guess i could count to 20 
"enumerating" all it's issues, but mainly :

- it doesn't enumerate all processes for a strange reason i did not see winrar for instance
- second it is far from being as short as pinvoke bunche-of-methods needs

(i am using Winforms app, though you could hard code the `ProcessName` needed in order to "search" for the correct process)

most of comments here is by the author of well, most parts of the code 
i only modified it a little to have enum later so you could choose between searching via window title or process name

so this is the code:

main entry - create instance of class :

```
        pinvokers Pi = new pinvokers();

        // Find all Internet Explorer instances(i used winrar, as my second task in this project is also test application performance... later on, and again, using only native calls)

        Pi.FindWindows(0, pinvokers.SearchWin.ProcName, null, new Regex(TBX_SelectedWinName.Text), new pinvokers.FoundWindowCallback(pinvokers.foundWindowToPrint));



public class pinvokers
{


    // Win32 constants.
    const int WM_GETTEXT = 0x000D;
    const int WM_GETTEXTLENGTH = 0x000E;
    [DllImport("user32.Dll")]
    private static extern Boolean EnumChildWindows(int hWndParent, PChildCallBack lpEnumFunc, int lParam);
    [DllImport("user32.Dll")]
    private static extern int GetWindowText(int hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);
    [DllImport("user32.Dll")]
    private static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(int hWnd, out int lpdwProcessId);
    [DllImport("user32.Dll")]
    private static extern Int32 SendMessage(int hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, StringBuilder lParam);
    [DllImport("user32.Dll")]
    private static extern Int32 SendMessage(int hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern uint GetWindowModuleFileName(IntPtr hwnd,
       StringBuilder lpszFileName, uint cchFileNameMax);
    [DllImport("psapi.dll")]
    private static extern uint GetModuleFileNameEx(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hModule, StringBuilder lpFileName, int nSize);


    // The PChildCallBack delegate that we used with EnumWindows.
    private delegate bool PChildCallBack(int hWnd, int lParam);

    // This is an event that is run each time a window was found that matches the search criterias. The boolean
    // return value of the delegate matches the functionality of the PChildCallBack delegate function.
    static event FoundWindowCallback foundWindowCB;
    public delegate bool FoundWindowCallback(int hWnd);
    int parentHandle;
    Regex process;

   #region <<===========  not nedded - search by window title. i am looking to search via process name ===========>>

   /* <- commented all unsuesd
    Regex windowText;
    public static bool foundWindowToPrint(int handle)
    {
        // Print the window info.
        printWindowInfo(handle);

        // Continue on with next window.
        return true;
    }

    static void printWindowInfo(int handle)
    {

        // Get the text.
        int txtLength = SendMessage(handle, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0);
        StringBuilder sbText = new StringBuilder(txtLength + 1);
        SendMessage(handle, WM_GETTEXT, sbText.Capacity, sbText);

        // Now we can write out the information we have on the window.
        MessageBox.Show("Handle: " + handle);
        MessageBox.Show("Text  : " + sbText);

    }
     =====>end of un needed search bywindowtitle1
      */
     #endregion


    // my plan was to use enum instead of if !empty or null value for ither title name or process name so that's how the original code ditermin wich one to execute. 
    public enum SearchWin
    {
        Title, ProcName
    }

     //first method (and that's all i could really tell.. as it is full of callbacks and private extern, and delegates ... so complex

    public void FindWindows(int parentHandle, SearchWin By, Regex windowText, Regex process, FoundWindowCallback fwc)
    {
        this.parentHandle = parentHandle;

        //this.windowText = windowText;
        this.process = process;

        // Add the FounWindowCallback to the foundWindow event.
        foundWindowCB = fwc;

        // Invoke the EnumChildWindows function.
        EnumChildWindows(parentHandle, new PChildCallBack(enumChildWindowsCallback), 0);


    }



    // This function gets called each time a window is found by the EnumChildWindows function. The foun windows here
    // are NOT the final found windows as the only filtering done by EnumChildWindows is on the parent window handle.
    private bool enumChildWindowsCallback(int handle, int lParam)
    {

   #region <<===========  not nedded - search by window title. #2 ===========>>
        /* <--here too window title portion of code commented

        // If a window text was provided, check to see if it matches the window.
        if (windowText != null)
        {
            int txtLength = SendMessage(handle, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0);
            StringBuilder sbText = new StringBuilder(txtLength + 1);
            SendMessage(handle, WM_GETTEXT, sbText.Capacity, sbText);

            // If it does not match, return true so we can continue on with the next window.
            if (!windowText.IsMatch(sbText.ToString()))
                return true;
        }
        */

        #endregion //endr2


        // If a process name was provided, check to see if it matches the window.
        if (process != null)
        {
            int processID;
            GetWindowThreadProcessId(handle, out processID);

            // Now that we have the process ID, we can use the built in .NET function to obtain a process object.
            var ProcessName = GetProcNameByID(processID);

            // If it does not match, return true so we can continue on with the next window.
            if (!process.IsMatch(ProcessName))
                return true;
        }

        // If we get to this point, the window is a match. Now invoke the foundWindow event and based upon
        // the return value, whether we should continue to search for windows.
        return foundWindowCB(handle);
    }

    private string GetProcNameByID(int ProcID)
    {



        IntPtr hProcess = OpenProcess(0x0410, false, ProcID);

        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder(1000);
        GetWindowModuleFileName(hProcess, text, (uint)text.Capacity);
        //GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess, IntPtr.Zero, text, text.Capacity);

        //CloseHandle(hProcess); here i am trying to catch what enumeration of windows got in its net , all this code does work just copy and paste it .
        var t =  text.ToString();
        if (t.ToLower().Contains("inra")) 
        MessageBox.Show(t);
        return t;


    }
}
```

so could this be a little shorter is a side question 
main one is :

**Why does it not enumerate all the processes ?**

Comment: It's very difficult to work out what you are doing. Why don't you strip this down to the bare minimum? The excessive amount of rather vile code is somewhat off putting. Try and make it so that we want to answer. Clean and simple code. Clear specification of what you expect to happen, and what does happen. And make sure that we can reproduce. And specify targets and OS. For example are you building 32 bit process and running on 64 bit OS? Oh, you'll need to check for errors in your API calls. Omitting error checking means that nobody has any idea where your code fails. Don't omit error checking

Comment: @DavidHeffernan 
ok i think i'm done with pinvoke, were done. i have made some efforts until now . the question was posted 5 hours + add some 10 by myself before i got to this code i am posting . .NET wins by 300%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know if it is the best i could get or maybe someone who knows what he is doing with win api, or p/invoke or if i had to try and make unmanagedLand win over .net built in calsses 
i might have rolled my sleeves and put some c++ code together (will probbably take another week)
and compile it to a dll to get all functions together in one DLL (should it do some perfomance gain)
and then i might have cut some gap .
(by the way now it is much closer to system diagnostic results thogh i thought it will be much faster and i was wrong)

but still it was only for knowing i am safe to use .net C# 
and to trust microsoft for knowing much better than me (: how to make a good proggraming language.

this is the code i was using to make it through all those dllllls import. i should have known that  import anything and it costs( here it might be the import tax that is costely)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }


    private void But_StartPinvoke_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var userInputOK = TBX_SelectedProcessName.userInput();
        if(!userInputOK)
            MessageBox.Show(RApss.mesgs.EmptyTbx);
        RApss.Strings.UserInput = TBX_SelectedProcessName.Text;
        RApss.Globs.TbxPname = TBX_SelectedProcessName.Text.AddSufixEXE();
        doWarmUp();

        Stopwatch SwGpbn = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        SwGpbn.Start();

        //string _netProcName = Process.GetProcessesByName(RApss.Strings.UserInput)[0].ProcessName;
        Process p = Process.GetProcessesByName(RApss.Strings.UserInput)[0];
        if (p.ProcessName.ResultFetched())
        SwGpbn.Stop();
        var msElps_Net4 = SwGpbn.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        SwGpbn.Reset();
        SwGpbn.Start();
        EnumProcessesV3.GetProcessByName();
        SwGpbn.Stop();
        var msElpsNat = SwGpbn.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        SwGpbn.Reset();



        SwGpbn.Reset();
        if (RApss.Globs.Result.ResultFetched()) MessageBox.Show(string.Concat(RApss.Globs.Result, "\r\nWas Fetched In: ", msElpsNat, " Via PinVoke\r\n Was Fetched In: ", msElps_Net4," Via C#.NET !" ));
    }

    private void doWarmUp()
    {
        List<string> swarm = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
        {
           swarm.Add((i + 1 *500).ToString());
        }
    }
}

public class RApss
{
    public class Globs
    {
        public static string TbxPname;
        public static string Result = string.Empty;
    }
    public class Strings
    {
        public static string intputForProcessName = "Requiered Process Name";
        public static string UserInput = string.Empty;
    }

    public class mesgs
    {
        public static string EmptyTbx = string.Concat("please fill ", Strings.intputForProcessName, " field");
    }
} 
   public class EnumProcessesV3
   {


    #region APIS
    [DllImport("psapi")]
    private static extern bool EnumProcesses(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U4)] [In][Out] IntPtr[] processIds,
        UInt32 arraySizeBytes, 
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] out UInt32 bytesCopied);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags dwDesiredAccess, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool bInheritHandle, IntPtr dwProcessId);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

    [DllImport("psapi.dll")]
    static extern uint GetModuleFileNameEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr hModule, [Out] StringBuilder lpBaseName, [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int nSize);

    [DllImport("psapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool EnumProcessModules(IntPtr hProcess,
    [Out] IntPtr lphModule,
    uint cb,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] out uint lpcbNeeded);

    [DllImport("psapi.dll")]
    static extern uint GetModuleBaseName(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr hModule, [Out] StringBuilder lpBaseName, [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int nSize);
    #endregion

    #region ENUMS

    [Flags]
    enum ProcessAccessFlags : uint
    {
        All = 0x001F0FFF,
        Terminate = 0x00000001,
        CreateThread = 0x00000002,
        VMOperation = 0x00000008,
        VMRead = 0x00000010,
        VMWrite = 0x00000020,
        DupHandle = 0x00000040,
        SetInformation = 0x00000200,
        QueryInformation = 0x00000400,
        Synchronize = 0x00100000
    }
    #endregion

    public static void GetProcessByName()
    {
        UInt32 arraySize = 120;
        UInt32 arrayBytesSize = arraySize * sizeof(UInt32);
        IntPtr[] processIds = new IntPtr[arraySize];
        UInt32 bytesCopied;

        bool success = EnumProcesses(processIds, arrayBytesSize, out bytesCopied);
        #region <<=========== some cleanUps  ============>>


        // trying to check what could have been taking extra mssssnds


        //Console.WriteLine("success={0}", success);
        //Console.WriteLine("bytesCopied={0}", bytesCopied);

        //if (!success)
        //{
        //    MessageBox.Show("Boo!");
        //    return;
        //}
        //if (0 == bytesCopied)
        //{
        //    MessageBox.Show("Nobody home!");
        //    return;
        //}
        #endregion
        UInt32 numIdsCopied = bytesCopied >> 2;
        #region <<===========same here commenting anything that might cost nerowing the options   ============>>





        //if (0 != (bytesCopied & 3))
        //{
        //    UInt32 partialDwordBytes = bytesCopied & 3;

        //    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("EnumProcesses copied {0} and {1}/4th DWORDS...  Please ask it for the other {2}/4th DWORD",
        //        numIdsCopied, partialDwordBytes, 4 - partialDwordBytes));
        //    return;
        //}
        //taking initialisation of SB out of loop was a winning thought but nada no change maybe in nanos

        #endregion



        for (UInt32 index = numIdsCopied; index> 1 ; index--) // reversing from last process id(chitting) to erlier process id did not help to win the contest
        {
            StringBuilder szProcessName = new StringBuilder(1000);
            int x = szProcessName.Capacity;
            string sName = PrintProcessName(processIds[index-1],szProcessName,x);
            if (sName.Equals(RApss.Globs.TbxPname)) // tryng hardcoded value instead of reading from a variable.(GlobalsClass)
            {
                RApss.Globs.Result = sName; 
                break;
            }
            ////////IntPtr PID = processIds[index];
            ////////Console.WriteLine("Name '" + sName + "' PID '" + PID + "'");
        }
    }


    static string PrintProcessName(IntPtr processID, StringBuilder sb, int Cpcty)
    {
        string sName = "";
        //bool bFound = false;
        IntPtr hProcess = OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags.QueryInformation | ProcessAccessFlags.VMRead, false, processID);
        if (hProcess != IntPtr.Zero)
        {

            IntPtr hMod = IntPtr.Zero;
            uint cbNeeded = 0;
            EnumProcessModules(hProcess, hMod, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr)), out cbNeeded);
            if (GetModuleBaseName(hProcess, hMod, sb, Cpcty) > 0)
            {
                sName = sb.ToString();

                //bFound = true;
            }

            // Close the process handle
            CloseHandle(hProcess);
        }
        //if (!bFound)
        //{
        //    sName = "<unknown>";
        //}
        return sName;
    }

  }
}
namespace RExt
{

    public static class UserInputs
    {
        public static bool userInput(this TextBox tbxId)
        {
            return tbxId.Text.Length > 1;
        }
    }
    public static class strExt
    {
        public static bool ResultFetched(this string StrToCheck)
        {
            return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(StrToCheck);
        }
        public static string AddSufixEXE(this string StrToAppendEXE)
        {
            return string.Concat(StrToAppendEXE, ".exe");
        }
    }
}
```

if thats not working, make sure the project is targeting x86 CPU and Rebuild 
for some reason i did not check what is needed to make it suit both x64 & x86